# Silverlight Web Service

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Below is the code i used to consume web servcie in SilverLight.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      BasicHttpBinding bind = new BasicHttpBinding();
      EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://loalhost/Service.asmx");
      ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient(bind, endpoint);
      client.RunHelloCompleted += new EventHandler<RunHelloCompletedEventArgs>(client_RunQwinCompleted);
      client.RunHelloAsync(command);
 }

 void client_RunHelloCompleted(object sender, RunHelloCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
      txtProcess.Text=Process(e.Result);
 }
```

I want to know a way that after i run RunHelloAsync(Command), I want to  get the returned result without going to Completed event. Please advise me. thank you.

Comment: Why can't you do what you need in the completed event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer : You can't.  Everything in Silverlight is Asynchronous so there is no way to block after the `client.RunHelloAsync(command)` call and wait for the result.

Long answer : There are ways to simulate working with calls in a synchronous fashion, but the calls still being made asynchronously.  Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855129/silverlight-wait-end-async-method-in-sync-method/2857456#2857456) for a few more answers.